# Android recurring events with shifting exception

Tags: android, events, calendar

I want to add an recurring event to the calendar but with some exceptions where the event is shifted to another date. I've read to several tutorials but I can't find a solution.

Is this behavior even possible?

Comment: Android Calendar Recurring Exceptions are very similar to Exchange Recurring Exceptions. Each "exception" item represents *when* the event would occur and the additional information (e.g. removed; or "exception date/time" which uses the DTSTART/DTEND properties to specify the new recurrence exception time). The class http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.EventsColumns.html#ORIGINAL_ID lists the relevant properties to "associate" a recurring exception with the recurring slot it is altering.

Comment: That means I have to add a "normal" recurring event and then find every event that has to be shifted and shift it by hand?

Comment: Yes. There is one master item and then N exception items associated with various would-be-event-times, for as many exceptions as required. This approach is ideal when exceptions are the .. exception, not the rule.

Comment: But it is still possible to delete the whole event, even the shifted exceptions? Right?

Comment: Recurring exceptions *only* exist in context of a master recurrence item/series. Removing the master removes all associated recurrence exceptions.

Comment: But how do I find my exceptions?